# Какие недочеты в моей верстке header'a и hero секции [Code review]?

Tags: инспекция-кода

Верстаю относительно с недавнего времени, ниже проект где только хэдер и главная секция сверстана. Верстал по БЭМ. Есть ли какие-то критические ошибки, или в целом все нормально? Верстка с зазором на адаптацию в будущем. Меня очень смущают кнопки вверху (Join, Sign in, Shopping bag), т.к я явно задал высоту и у меня под каждую кнопку отдельный элемент. Напишите пожалуйста какие ошибки у меня, чтобы в дальнейшем их избегать. Также приложил макет

index.html:
https://github.com/stn28/fpress/blob/main/index.html

style.css:
https://github.com/stn28/fpress/blob/main/css/style.css

preview:
https://stn28.github.io/fpress/

Comment: Единственное, что смущает - использование 3 шрифтов. Обычно используется 1 шрифт, иногда 2. Плюс основной шрифт обычно указывается не для каждого элемента, а в body. И лично я бы добавил изменение стилей кнопок при наведении.

Comment: 1) Я бы не давал в .header-login высоту, ошибка начинающего верстальщика - высоту нужно формировать благодаря внутренним элементам. Самый высокий элемент - это 3 элемента как я вижу, можно им задать высоту в 73px вместо .header-login. Это даст вам возможность не думать в будущем при адаптивности о высоте, она сама будет подстраиваться под содержимое.

Comment: 2) Не вводите container в БЭМ - это уникальный класс, который всегда сам по себе. Он у вас должен быть по умолчанию прописан в стилях перед вёрсткой с нужными размерами под все разрешения - можно их взять с bootstrap и доработать, если у вас необычные размеры container и в будущем он сам будет вам неважно в какой секции вы верстаете ставить нужный вам размер. Если container различаются как у вас в header и hero добавляете дополнительный класс например w-1100 и в стилях задаёте другую ширину.

Comment: 3) SVG header-login__bag-image - вы не правильно грузите, во первых локально нужно грузить, а во вторых как вы цвет его поменяете при наведении? Это сейчас у вас дизайн без :hover эффектов, а в будущем?

Comment: 4) .header-bottom__nav - не ограничивайте ширину max-width: 770px; и уберите justify-content - вместо этого просто задайте column-gap: 20px; так как ограничивая ширину вы не даёте возможность добавить ещё одну ссылку в меню, хотя место ещё есть.

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи спасибо вам что все подробно расписали!